# Why isn't 'which -a' listing the executable that will run?

Tags: bash, path, executable

According to the documentation for `which`, it should "list all instances of executables" (`-a`) "in the user's path", and based on my understanding of what executables are and what a path is, that means, simply that the first listed item should be the one executed when I enter the name of the searched for command.

But that's not the behavior I'm seeing.

```sh
~ $ which -a speedtest 
/usr/local/bin/speedtest
~ $ speedtest -V
curl 7.64.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin20.0) ...
~ $ /usr/local/bin/speedtest -V
Speedtest by Ookla 1.0.0.2 (5ae238b) Darwin 20.4.0 x86_64
```

I expect that the `speedtest` returned first by which (Ookla's) would be the one that's found first and executed but it's not and a different one (curl's) is executed instead. Moreover, the `speedtest` that is excited isn't even retuned by `which` at all.

What's going on here? How is this even possible? Why isn't `which -a` listing the excitable that will run?

---

```sh
~ $ ls -al /usr/local/bin/speedtest
lrwxr-xr-x  1 Orome  admin  39 May 18 13:51 /usr/local/bin/speedtest -> ../Cellar/speedtest/1.0.0/bin/speedtest
~ $ /usr/local/bin/../Cellar/speedtest/1.0.0/bin/speedtest -V
Speedtest by Ookla 1.0.0.2 (5ae238b) Darwin 20.4.0 x86_64 ...
```

```sh
~ $ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.8(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0) ...
```

```sh
~ $ echo $PATH
/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin
```

```sh
~ $ whereis speedtest
```

Comment: `which` is not a bash built-in. Use `type` instead.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to run `hash -r` after an install or path update?

Comment: @oguzismail Aha! `which` doesn't list aliases! That's an answer.

Comment: @orome `which` only searches the directories in `PATH` for executables; but when the shell goes to execute a command, it first looks for an alias by that name, then for a shell function, then for a shell builtin, and it's only if it doesn't find any of those that it searches `PATH`. In bash, `type` knows how to check for aliases, functions, and builtins as well as look at `PATH`. In zsh, `whence` is the command that knows how to check all the possibilities.

Comment: Yes, @oguzismail already answered. That would be an accepted answer.